# Check if object is null, then check if that object holds not null reference to another object

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee

I have a condition like this:

```
if (someObject != null)
    {
        templateUri = someObject .getSettingsObject() != null
                ? someObject .getSettingsObject().getPlanUri() : null;
    }
```

Instead of using multiple null checks, can I club this conditions into a single statement and run my code without getting NULL pointer Exception?

Comment: Use `Optional<T>` for your `SettingsObject` and `PlanUri`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be better create a method to handle the case but with a single statement you could do this:

```
templateUri = (someObject != null) ? (someObject.getSettingsObject()!=null ? someObject.getSettingsObject().getPlanUri() : null ) : templateUri;
```

If `someObject` is null `templateUri` will be replaced with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with nested conditional operator `( ? : )`

```
templateUri = someObject == null ? null 
                   : someObject .getSettingsObject() == null ? null 
                   : someObject .getSettingsObject().getPlanUri();
```